# Update only in case where its not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want update a column(a) from table1 with select from table2 but making update only when in table2 existing column(b) is not null. I dont want use where statement (is not null) cause it will influence all my code.

Example of my code:

```
update table1 set column(a) = (select column(b) from table2)
```

I'm trying something like this

```
update table1 set column(a) = not null(select column(b) from table2)
```

Example:

```
update ExpressMarketCheck set Barcode = (select barcode from ExpressMarket), Name=(select name from expressmarket), price=(select price from expressmarket)
```

Comment: What does "influence all my code" mean?  Why can you nod use a simple, standard `WHERE` clause?

Comment: What is the problem with WHERE clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to achieve your constraint.

```
Update ExpressMarketCheck set Barcode = (select barcode from ExpressMarket where barcode IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Uncorrelated sub-query?

Comment: thats exactly what he doesn't want. " I dont want use where statement (is not null)"

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. Initially that constraint wasn't there when I post the answer.

Comment: Its ok i will it works with little changes in my code! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

mySQL has an `IFNULL` function, so you could do:

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET your_column_name= "data",
scan_created_date = ISNULL( your_column_name, "data" )
WHERE id = X
```

Comment: in SQL-Server you can use `ISNULL()`

Comment: thanks for pointing to it -:)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `join`:

```
update emc
    set Barcode = em.barcode, 
        Name = em.name,
        price= em.price
     from ExpressMarketCheck emc join
          expressmarket em
          on emc.?? = em.??;
```

I cannot tell from your question what columns should be used for the `join`.   The `??` are placeholders.